# Update a Particular Cell in a Table in DBT Using Where Statements

Tags: sql, dbt

Hi I have a following table Sales

| Country | Sales | Sale_Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| US | 2 | 12-06-2022 |
| JP | 2 | 15-06-2022 |

I have to write a SQL query to update the paticular cell in dbt. I want to change Sale_Date for US.

Now my query is-

```
UPDATE `sales`
SET 
    Sale_Date = '2022-06-16'
WHERE
    Country = 'US'
```

However, In dbt I get following error

```
Server error: Database Error in rpc request (from remote system)
Syntax error: Expected end of input but got keyword LIMIT at [4:1]
```

What am I missing? I am fairly new to dbt.

Comment: provide db script

Comment: which warehouse do you use dbt on top of?

Answer (score 0):

dbt is thought to mainly be used with `SELECT` statements. You can find a bit more context [here](https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/faqs/why-not-write-dml).

What you might want to do is to just apply that transformation using a `SELECT` statement as follows:

```sql
select
  [...],
  case when country = 'US' then '2022-06-16'::date else sale_date end as <new_column_name>
from {{ ref('your_staging_model') }}. -- or {{ source('your_schema', 'your_source_table')}}
```

So now, you will have a dbt model materialized either as a view, a table, or whatever you prefer, that contains a column with the `UPDATE`-like transformation that you needed.